# leJOS build help!

Tags: compiling

I'm currently trying to install leJOS in my Ubuntu laptop (12.04) and I've followed the instructions from here but I'm unable to build it. 
(http://code.google.com/p/lego-mindstorms-3d-printing-machine/wiki/SetupLeJOS)

When I type "ant" it shows the following error:

```
Buildfile: /opt/leJOS_NXJ/build/build.xml

jlibnxt:

clean:

jlibnxt:

BUILD FAILED
/opt/leJOS_NXJ/build/build.xml:87: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/opt/leJOS_NXJ/build/libnxt/build.xml:39: Can't create history file

Total time: 0 seconds
```

Can somebody help me fix this error?

Oh and one more thing - how does one set environment paths/variables? (Which is the next step)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try running `sudo ant` instead.

You're compiling in the `/opt/` folder, which requires root privileges to create & delete files in.

The `sudo` command will run ant with the needed rights.